# Pourquoi « licéité » mais « licite » ?

Tags: étymologie

Le nom et l'adjectif ont manifestement le même sens, s'écrivent presque pareil et ont très vraisemblablement la même origine. Alors pourquoi ce *é* d'écart ?

Answer (score 4):

L'origine n'est pas tout à fait la même pour ces deux mots qui ont été « créés » à des époques assez distantes.

Selon le TLFi :

- [licite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/licite) (vient de *licitus*)

  > Étymol. et Hist. [Cf. le dér. licitement 1266] ca 1310 (Aimé, Ystoire de li Normant, éd. V. de Bartholomaeis, I, XXXVIII, p. 5). Empr. au lat.licitus « permis, légitime, licite ».
- [licéité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lic%C3%A9it%C3%A9) (vient de *licere*)

  > Étymol. et Hist. 1907 dr. canon. (Lar. pour tous). Dér. du lat. licere « être permis »; suff. -(i)té*; cf. le m. fr. licitité (1530 Palsgr., p. 237 b), dér. de licite*.

Comment: En gros, 'licéité' est le croisement entre 'licitité' et 'licere'.

Comment: @MathieuBouville: C'est à peu près comme ça que je vois les choses.

Answer (score 0):

On ne trouve pas ce mot dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie. On ne le trouve pas non plus dans le Littré. Il figure cependant dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lic%C3%A9it%C3%A9) et la variante « licité » n'existe pas ;

> DR. CANON. Caractère d'un acte permis par la loi. Toutes les conditions sont observées pour que le sacrement soit administré conformément aux exigences de la morale et du droit canonique. (...) la licéité et la validité posent des conditions à la fois dans le ministre, le sujet et le sacrement (Théol. cath.t. 14, 11939, p. 635).
>   Prononc. : [liseite]. Étymol. et Hist. 1907 dr. canon. (Lar. pour tous). Dér. du lat. licere « être permis »; suff. -(i)té*; cf. le m. fr. licitité (1530 Palsgr., p. 237 b), dér. de licite*.

Il ne m'est pas possible de trouver plus d'information sur l'étymologie que n'en contient le paragraphe dédié à l'étymologie du TLFi. Je peux cependant supposer qu'il n'est pas impossible qu'un é ait été ajouter de sorte à différencier clairement le participe passé de « liciter » du nom, le é se trouvant déjà dans le latin « licere ».